# How to get text in QlineEdit when QpushButton is pressed in a string?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt4, qlineedit

I am trying to implement a function. My code is given below.

I want to get the text in lineedit with objectname 'host' in a string say 'shost' when the user clicks the pushbutton with name 'connect'. How can I do this? I tried and failed. How do I implement this function?

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *


class Form(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)

        le = QLineEdit()
        le.setObjectName("host")
        le.setText("Host")
        pb = QPushButton()
        pb.setObjectName("connect")
        pb.setText("Connect") 
        layout.addWidget(le)
        layout.addWidget(pb)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.connect(pb, SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.button_click)

        self.setWindowTitle("Learning")

    def button_click(self):
    #i want the text in lineedit with objectname 
    #'host' in a string say 'shost'. when the user click 
    # the pushbutton with name connect.How do i do it?
    # I tried and failed. How to implement this function?




app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Form()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

Now how do I implement the function "button_click" ? I have just started with pyQt!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

My first suggestion is to use Qt Designer to create your GUIs.  Typing them out yourself sucks, takes more time, and you will definitely make more mistakes than Qt Designer.

Here are some [PyQt tutorials](https://web.archive.org/web/20130704101140/http://www.diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/Tutorials) to help get you on the right track.  The first one in the list is where you should start.

A good guide for figuring out what methods are available for specific classes is the [PyQt4 Class Reference](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/classes.html).  In this case, you would look up `QLineEdit` and see the there is a `text` method.

To answer your specific question:

To make your GUI elements available to the rest of the object, preface them with `self.`

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import SIGNAL
from PyQt4.QtGui import QDialog, QApplication, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QFormLayout

class Form(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)

        self.le = QLineEdit()
        self.le.setObjectName("host")
        self.le.setText("Host")
        
        self.pb = QPushButton()
        self.pb.setObjectName("connect")
        self.pb.setText("Connect") 
        
        layout = QFormLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.le)
        layout.addWidget(self.pb)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.connect(self.pb, SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.button_click)
        self.setWindowTitle("Learning")

    def button_click(self):
        # shost is a QString object
        shost = self.le.text()
        print shost
        

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Form()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: I'm getting this error! 
AttributeError: 'Form' object has no attribute 'le'

Comment: You need to name it `self.le` in your `__init__` function.  Everywhere you use it in your `Form` class it should be `self.le`.

Comment: I didn't get you. Sorry, I'm just getting started with these... i used the code which you gave, and the error came. I think in it, its already self.le

Comment: I don't get the error when I run the above code.  I'm using Python 2.6, what version are you using?

Comment: Python 2.6.5 under ubuntu 64 bit.

Comment: It worked! Thanx. There was a syntax error. Thank You Very Much!

Comment: shost = self.le.text() will probably give a QString output. Cast it with a str() to get a meaningfull text.

Answer (score 2):

The object name is not very important.
what you should be focusing at is the variable that stores the lineedit object (le) and your pushbutton object(pb)

```
QObject(self.pb, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.button_clicked)

def button_clicked(self):
  self.le.setText("shost")
```

I think this is what you want.
I hope i got your question correctly :)

Answer (score 2):

**Acepted solution implemented in PyQt5**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QFormLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QPushButton, QLineEdit)

class Form(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)

        self.le = QLineEdit()
        self.le.setObjectName("host")
        self.le.setText("Host")

        self.pb = QPushButton()
        self.pb.setObjectName("connect")
        self.pb.setText("Connect")
        self.pb.clicked.connect(self.button_click)

        layout = QFormLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.le)
        layout.addWidget(self.pb)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.setWindowTitle("Learning")

    def button_click(self):
        # shost is a QString object
        shost = self.le.text()
        print (shost)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Form()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

Short and general answer is:

```
self.input = QLineEdit()
your_text = self.input.text()
```